# Menu available on questions but not answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The UI is inconsistent between questions and answers.

> [image: I can edit!]

There is a menu available on clicking *Edited* on the question ...

> [image: I cant edit!]

... which seems to be missing on answers.

Comment: You can edit questions in the app?  What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be more inclined to agree if that was the purpose of that button.  Right now, it serves a more limited subset of functionality.

[image]

Perhaps soon one can edit from the app... but not yet.

(EDIT: I can't edit others' content, but I can edit my own - that is, the "menu" is available when the content belongs to me.  It's a good start...)

Comment: Thats not it. I can see the menu on **all questions** but not on **any answers**. My initial phrasing of the question was incorrect. Sorry about that!

Comment: Find an answer you've authored, and you should see it.  I've seen it on this very Meta post.

Comment: This is correct. To clear some things up: Currently clicking that small indicator brings up a dialog of actions you can perform onto questions. None of those actions other than edit exist in the app yet, therefore that dialog does not exist for the majority of answers yet. I'm personally not the biggest fan of that UI for going to the dialog, and will most likely change it to be more obvious in the future, but that should explain the UI differences.

Comment: Also, you can currently edit questions in the app if it's a question you've posted or you're a moderator on the site, but you can only edit answers if it's an answer you've posted. This will be fixed eventually to add in all the different cases in which you can edit questions and answers.