# Show community wikis differently in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, community-wiki

I'm requesting that Community Wiki questions and answers display differently than non-wiki ones or otherwise indicate that they are wikis.

Example CW post in browser:

[image: CW Example]

How the same post looks in the app:

[image: In the app]

One can clearly see it is impossible to distinguish between CW and regular posts in the Android app.

Comment: CW is not of much use till the ability to edit answers is added.

Comment: @AsheeshR: I just did (see below)

Comment: Only your own..

Comment: @AsheeshR: Ahh I see, thanks. Guess I need to add another feature request!

Comment: Its coming in sometime. [The dev is aware of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194895/menu-available-on-questions-but-not-answers#comment613556_194899).

Comment: @AsheeshR: Ahh ok, I couldn't find a feature request for that. Guess it is kind of a given though.

Comment: Any update on this? I still can't find the update in the app.

Comment: @WrichikBasu bad news: new features will not be added to the android app anymore, it is final and official. So this feature will never be added.

Answer (score 3):

This would be possible by "borrowing" the current format from the browser for CW posts.

This would definitely help with helping users know which posts are CW and which are not. At the very least, there should be some banner at the bottom of the answer that says "Community Wiki", with the words being a hyperlink to the Help Center article on what CW posts are.